# Finding explicit given a predefined image by a function.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble computing every possible mapping that gives a definition by a function. I would like a general explanation to apply to every scenario. I'm aware that it's possible given both the kernel and the linear mapping, but I'm not sure otherwise. Here's an example:

https://yutsumura.com/find-a-linear-transformation-whose-image-range-is-a-given-subspace/

but there is not a line. I have also looked at many posts on MSE, and I could not come up with anything.

I don't know if it's relevant, but I was messing around, and I found a basis for $5x$ to be the column vector $[1, 5]$.

Comment: Can you come up with a way to ensure that’s the column space of a $2\times2$ matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an elementary way to do it.

You want a projection onto the line. Your linear transformation is $(x,y)^T\mapsto (ax+by, cx+dy)^T$ for some $a,b,c,d$ and you want the second component to be five times the first, i.e. $$ cx+dy = 5(ax+by)$$ for all $x$ and $y.$ The only way this can be true for all $x$ and $y$ is for $c=5a$ and $d=5b.$ In other words, the transformation's matrix has the form $$\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}= \pmatrix{a&b\\5a&5b}.$$ for some arbitrary $a$ and $b$. (But note $a$ and $b$ cannot both be zero or the range is just zero, not the line $y=5x.$)

A more advanced way to look at it, which makes contact with the page you linked to, is to realize you want your image space to be the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $(1,5)^T.$ This means the column space of the matrix needs to be this space, so the columns must both be proportional to $(1,5)^T,$ and at least one of them nonzero.  Of course the matrix we wrote down above is the most general one of that kind.

Answer (score 0):

Linear maps can be uniquely defined by how the act on a basis. Pick your favourite basis $(v_1, v_2)$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the linear maps you're interested are the ones that map both of these vectors onto this line. The only exception is the $0$ map, so make sure that at least one of $v_1, v_2$ maps to a non-zero vector on the line.